# I do not want to add new record while refreshing

Tags: php, mysql, insert, refresh

I am junior programmer and stuck in making this simple form. 
This is my script and every time I press f5, it will automatic add last same record as new record but I want to add only when submit button is pressed. Please help.

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_selectdb("test_database") or die (mysql_error());

    if(isset($_POST['s1']))
    {
        $nm=$_POST["name"];
        $gen=$_POST["gen"];
        $add=$_POST["add"];
        $tech=$_POST["tech"];

        $iq=mysql_query("insert into formcheck (name,gender,address,tech) values ('{$nm}','{$gen}','{$add}','{$tech}' )") or die (mysql_error());

        if($iq)
        {
            echo "<script> alert('Record inserted Successfully') </script>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error occurred in inserting a record";
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" name="f1">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Name" name="name" required="">
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="gen" required="">Male
            <input type="radio" name="gen">Female 
            <br>
            <textarea name="add" placeholder="Address" required="" rows="5" cols="20" draggable="true"></textarea>
            <br>
            <select name="tech" required="">
                <option value=""> Select Technology </option>
                <option value="p"> PHP </option>
                <option value="i"> iPhone </option>
                <option value="a"> ASP </option>
                <option value="h"> HTML/CSS3 </option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Click here" name="s1">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So do a validation like whether the record exists in database. Otherwise will you insert same record if tried with same data multiple times.?

Comment: one simple answer is to add a session token.

Comment: You can use redirection page self with jquery or php header

Answer (score 0):

Write all your php code in a separate file say- **insert.php**

and edit the `<form>` tag to-

```
<form method="post" action="insert.php" name="f1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a redirect after submitting data to the database. It's a common practise.
make a different file for insertion and then redirect back . this will solve the issue.
the $_post array need to be cleared un less duplicate enteries will be entered